# Error - insert datetime to database "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 5 and I have a problem when storing dates into the database and when I try to create a blog and then I hit the button to insert data to database I will get this error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

The code in the model:

```
 [Display(Name = "Date")]
 [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

The code in the view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateBlog";
}

<h2>Create Blog</h2>

<form action="/Blog/CreateBlog/" name="myForm" method="post">

    Title: <input type="text" name="Overskrift" />
    <br />
    <br />
    text: <input type="text" name="Tekst" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Date: <input type="datetime" name="date" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    @ViewBag.MSG

</form>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: share your controller code

Comment: @Suprajv : public class BlogController : Controller
    {
        BlogFac bf = new BlogFac();

        //Vis eller Get All Blog
        public ActionResult VisBlog()
        {

            return View(bf.GetAll());

        }

        public ActionResult CreateBlog()
        {

            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateBlog(Blog b)
        {
            bf.Insert(b);
            ViewBag.MSG = " blog is createdt";

            return View();

        }

Comment: You will get this error if you are not inserting the proper date to MSSQL database

Comment: May be datetime is not getting passed from view to controller

Comment: i dont think so, they can passing data to each other

Comment: Did you debug the code and check the value of datetime being passed to sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Adding date Cannot BE Empty")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/1800", "3/4/9000", ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[Display(Name = "Adding Date")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

or Replace this

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

with this

```
public DateTime Date 
{
   get
   {
      return this.dates.HasValue
         ? this.dates.Value
         : DateTime.Now;
   }

   set { this.dates= value; }
}
private DateTime? dates= null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure to initialize the date object. otherwise, it will take the default value which is outside the date range that is allowed in SQL Server date column.

If this is hte date of the blog creation, then you must remove it from the UI HTML and set it in the controller by using the code:

```
b.Date = DateTime.Now;
```